# payment system intergration for custom epos software

Tags: java, point-of-sale

I'm trying my hand in the food industry. I'm going to be developing my epos system in house. All the fancy touch screen systems cost an arm and a leg. I was wondering what are my options if I wanted to integrate a chip and pin device as well? Could I use something like paypal? I doubt supermarkets use such a system though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [Openbravo POS](http://www.openbravo.com/)? It's great for a basic EPOS system, and has features such as Restaurant Mode (tables etc), as well as reporting facilities etc.  It's also free :-)

If you want to use Chip & Pin though, you'll need to write a custom Java module to compile into Openbravo, to link between whatever software your C&P device provides, and Openbravo itself.  I've done this for a custom Openbravo installation, but it is specific to the C&P device provider.

PayPal is an online web payment service provider - this is different to the hardware-based C&P.

**Edit** you're probably also better off talking to your bank about their options regarding C&P - they may be able to offer you such a service, or recommend a partner to lease you the hardware and provide support etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Ocius for PC](http://www.commidea.com/pages/index.asp?content_id=156), is a pre-approved chip and pin solution from [Commidea](http://www.commidea.com/), which you can integrate with your software.  You will need to have your integration tested by Commidea before you can deploy to any live sites.

Changing your software to work with Ocius should take a few days of coding and testing.

[YESpay](http://www.yes-pay.com/) also offer [chip and pin](http://www.yes-pay.com/EasyVHospitality.aspx) solutions, but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [ERPLY POS](http://www.erply.com) , its also free, usable over WWW and its really nice UI